# Pixel vs. Rem? What’s your take on this?

Tags: css, pixel

What’s the main difference between pixel(px) and rem? And when should I use px over rem?

Answer (score 0):

**Pixels** are an absolute unit. This means that a heading that has the `font-size 30px` always has exactly this size, namely 30 pixels. No matter what happens around it.

You can only tell how big a heading is that is specified in 2.3**em** when you know what environment it is in. This is because the unit em refers to the next higher container.

The unit **rem** is identical to the unit em, but the element to which this unit refers is the root element, i.e. the html element.